# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTokens') Occurred while linting /app/layout.tsx:16 Rule: "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I don't understand why the function that returns JSX is being linted with the rule `"@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function"` when running the "next lint" script.

The code at line 16 of the `layout.tsx` file is as follows:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.variable}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

As you can see, the function is not empty, and it does not violate the `"@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function"` rule. However, the following error message occurs:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTokens')
Occurred while linting /Users/najaewan/Desktop/f-lab/clothesgpt/packages/clothes_gpt/app/layout.tsx:16
Rule: "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function"
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I also considered the possibility of a misconfigured `eslintrc.js` file, but I couldn't figure out the cause.

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./packages/*/tsconfig.json', 'typescript-eslint/parser'],
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  extends: [
    'next/core-web-vitals',
    'plugin:@next/next/recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'
  ],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react', 'react-hooks', 'prettier', 'jest'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['warn', { args: 'none' }],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 'error',
    'react/display-name': 0,
    'react/self-closing-comp': 'error',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      'error',
      { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }
    ],
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'no-undef': 0,
    'no-constant-condition': 1,
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        bracketSpacing: true,
        printWidth: 80,
        singleQuote: true,
        trailingComma: 'none',
        tabWidth: 2,
        useTabs: false,
        bracketSameLine: false,
        semi: true
      }
    ]
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/*.ts?(x)'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      extends: [
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'
      ],
      parserOptions: {
        project: ['tsconfig.json', './packages/**/tsconfig.json'],
        ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true
        },
        ecmaVersion: 2018,
        sourceType: 'module'
      }
    },
    {
      files: [
        'packages/clothes_gpt/**/*.ts?(x)',
        'packages/clothes_gpt/**/*.js?(x)'
      ],
      rules: {
        '@next/next/no-img-element': 'off'
      },
      settings: {
        'import/parsers': {
          '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx']
        },
        'import/resolver': {
          typescript: {
            project: path.resolve(
              `${__dirname}/packages/clothes_gpt/tsconfig.json`
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      pragma: 'React',
      version: 'detect'
    }
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true
  }
};
```

I don't understand why "next lint" is linting the function that returns JSX with the `"@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function"` rule. You can reproduce this error in the repository available [here](https://github.com/f-lab-edu/ClothesGPT/tree/chore/eslint)

When running "next lint" in the root/packages/clothes_gpt directory, you should see the error.

**Expected Behavior**: When running the "next lint" script, functions that return JSX should not trigger the "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function" rule.

**Current Behavior**: Functions that return JSX are triggering the "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function" rule.

Comment: any luck? I am having the same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Could this be a bug introduced recently?

Comment: I just solved my problem by disabling that rule in that specific file from my eslint config file. Note that disabling it using a comment at the top of the file failed for some reason

Comment: One last comment: this only crashes ESLint executed from VSCode for me. From the terminal it runs just fine

Comment: are you on a monorepo project? if yes there's probably a mismatched packages

Comment: I had this problem as well when I set up according to turborepo guide (https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/linting/eslint). If I installed `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` in the `eslint-config-custom` package only, then I got this error. But if I installed it in every package, then it works. This is inconvenient though.

Comment: Update: I fixed my issue another way; in the `eslint-config-custom` package, everything needs to be `dependencies` and not `devDependencies`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I discovered the cause of my issue and resolved it.

The problem originated from a specific section in the eslintrc.js file, particularly within the plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended extension plugin.

[typescript-eslint/recommended](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended.ts)

In line 14 of the eslint plugin @typescript-eslint/recommended, the rule `'@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'error'` was set.

This rule was the reason behind the continuous linting of `@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function`. To overcome this, there are a couple of workarounds. One option is to avoid using the `@typescript-eslint/recommended` plugin altogether. Alternatively, you can override the rule by adding the `@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function` rule and setting it to `"off"`.

Here's an example configuration snippet demonstrating the override:

```
"overrides": [
   "extends": [
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
    ],
    "rules":{
      "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off"
    }
]
```

Regarding the question of why `@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function` returns JSX, it's best to refer to the specific rule file for detailed information. You can find it in [no-empty-function source code](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/no-empty-function.ts)

Answer (score 10):

I want to amplify a comment from @krehwell. In my case this was occurring for me because I had a monorepo setup with different versions of eslint. I was in the process of refactoring it all into a shared package.

Aligning the version of eslint solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by agreeing to the eslint version in the monorepo project